# Align, array, bullets

Tags: align, bullets

first of all, my apologies for my english, I wish I could write in english better than I do and I hope I can explain myself so you guys can understand what I want to do.
I'm new in LaTex, I started learning it a few days ago, found some useful resources about LaTex and some packages, and was able to write this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{xlop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@op@top}[4]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\ }c@{\hspace*{#1}}r}
        & \pgfmathprintnumber{#3} \\
        \smash{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{#2}} & \pgfmathprintnumber{#4} \\ \hline
    }
    \NewDocumentCommand{\@op@top@bottom}{m s O{1em} m m}{%
        \@op@top{#3}{#1}{#4}{#5}%
        \IfBooleanTF{#2}{}{%
            & \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{#4\@@op#5}\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}%
        }%
    \end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand{\OpAdd}{\def\@@op{+}\@op@top@bottom{$+$}}
\newcommand{\OpSub}{\def\@@op{-}\@op@top@bottom{$-$}}
\newcommand{\OpMul}{\def\@@op{*}\@op@top@bottom{$\times$}}
\newcommand{\OpDiv}{\def\@@op{/}\@op@top@bottom{$\div$}}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
    
    \OpAdd*[10pt]{1234}{5678} \par \bigskip
    \OpSub*[10pt]{246}{135} \par \bigskip
    \OpMul*[10pt]{12}{13} \par \bigskip
    \newcommand{\placeholder}[1]{--}% Print -- regardless of the input
    \newcommand{\gobble}[1]{}% Print <nothing> regardless of the input
%   \opdiv[resultstyle=\gobble,remainderstyle=\gobble]{196}{8}
    \newcommand\myrule[1]{\multicolumn{1}{| l}{#1}}
        \[
        \begin{array}{rl}
            478 & \myrule{7}\\
            \cline{2-2}
        \end{array}
        \]
    
\end{document}
```

It shows these four math operations:

[image]

As you guys can see, the division is not left aligned as the rest of the operations, and wonder how can I do that.
Besides, I'd like to know what would be the best way to add more operations, let's say 3 or 4 more aditions on the same row, and do the same on the other rows but show all the operations as if they were in an array, and finally, add a bullet to each one, like a), b), c), etc.
I'll really appreciate any help on this.
Regards.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for adding a minimal example document! Your division is aligned the way it is because you've wrapped it in `\[...\]`, which is for displayed math. Try using just `$...$` instead. The `tasks` package is a very nice package for creating groups of enumerated items.

Answer (score 1):

The `tasks` package is a nice package for arranging things in exercise-like format.  Your alignment problem was caused by using `\[ ... \]` display math instead of inline math. Here's all four of your examples in a row, and enumerated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{xlop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\usepackage{tasks}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@op@top}[4]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\ }c@{\hspace*{#1}}r}
        & \pgfmathprintnumber{#3} \\
        \smash{\raisebox{.5\normalbaselineskip}{#2}} & \pgfmathprintnumber{#4} \\ \hline
    }
    \NewDocumentCommand{\@op@top@bottom}{m s O{1em} m m}{%
        \@op@top{#3}{#1}{#4}{#5}%
        \IfBooleanTF{#2}{}{%
            & \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{#4\@@op#5}\pgfmathprintnumber{\result}%
        }%
    \end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand{\OpAdd}{\def\@@op{+}\@op@top@bottom{$+$}}
\newcommand{\OpSub}{\def\@@op{-}\@op@top@bottom{$-$}}
\newcommand{\OpMul}{\def\@@op{*}\@op@top@bottom{$\times$}}
\newcommand{\OpDiv}{\def\@@op{/}\@op@top@bottom{$\div$}}
\newcommand{\placeholder}[1]{--}% Print -- regardless of the input
\newcommand{\gobble}[1]{}% Print <nothing> regardless of the input
\newcommand\myrule[1]{\multicolumn{1}{| l}{#1}}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(4)    
\task    \OpAdd*[10pt]{1234}{5678} \par \bigskip
\task  \OpSub*[10pt]{246}{135} \par \bigskip
\task    \OpMul*[10pt]{12}{13} \par \bigskip
\task        $\begin{array}{rl}
            478 & \myrule{7}\\
            \cline{2-2}
        \end{array}$
\end{tasks}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you Alan! You've been very helpful and replied quickly!